# Micrium uC/FS file system Mount delay

Tags: embedded, filesystems, microcontroller, micrium

I am working on uC/FS Fat16 filesystem on Nor flash with spi.  Volume mount takes 3 Minutes, Even after initial(first time) mount, Each power-on mount takes 3 minutes.  How this timing can be reduced.

Comment: You first need to find out where the time is spent.

Comment: FSDev_NOR_LowMountHandler() in this function, within while for device block count of 128 times, time is spent, and in actual flow doesn't call block erase handler

Comment: Being without any insight in uC/FS: What does this function? Did you watch the SPI? Is there a lot of transfers? Does it build up many structures in RAM? Is the filesystem healthy?

Comment: @thebusybee uC/FS and other Micrium source have been released by Silabs and have been recently added to github. That function is at https://github.com/SiliconLabs/uC-FS/blob/master/Dev/NOR/fs_dev_nor.c#L2050

Comment: @DaV Well, the OP could show some effort and look into the sources. ;-) I'm just giving hints what to try next. The question lacks a lot of information.